# R Optimizing double for loop, matrix manipulation

Tags: r, matrix, dataframe

I am trying to manipulate column data in a two column matrix and output it as a data.frame.

The matrix that I have is in this format where both the values in the start and end columns are increasing and don't overlap. Also, there are always more Start entries than there are End entries.

Suppose I start with this matrix:

```
#       Start   End
#  [1,]     1     6
#  [2,]     2     9
#  [3,]     3    15
#  [4,]     7    NA
#  [5,]     8    NA
#  [6,]    11    NA
#  [7,]    12    NA
#  [8,]    14    NA
```

I want this double for loop to output a data.frame that groups all Start values less than an End value and associates it with that End value.

To clarify I want to output this:

```
#       Start   End
#  1    1,2,3     6
#  2      7,8     9
#  3 11,12,14    15
```

I tried a double for loop but I need something faster because I want to use this method on a larger matrix ~5 MB.

```
start_end <- matrix(c(1, 6, 2, 9, 3, 15, 7, NA, 8, NA, 11, NA, 12, NA, 14, NA), 
  nrow=8, 
  ncol=2)

# of non NA rows in column 2
non_nacol <- sum(is.na(start_end[,2]))

sorted.output <- data.frame(matrix(NA, nrow = nrow(start_end), ncol = 0))
sorted.output$start <- 0
sorted.output$end <- 0

#Sort and populate data frame
for (k in 1:non_nacol) {
  for (j in 1:nrow(start_end)) {
        if (start_end[j,1]<start_end[k,2]) {
        S <- (start_end[j,1])
        E <- (start_end[k,2])
        sorted.output$start[j] <- S
        sorted.output$end[j] <- E
        }
  }
}
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use Rcpp:

```
start_end <- matrix(c(1, 6, 2, 9, 3, 15, 7, NA, 8, NA, 11, NA, 12, NA, 14, NA), 
                    nrow=8, 
                    ncol=2, byrow = TRUE)

library(Rcpp)
cppFunction('
            DataFrame fun(const IntegerMatrix& Mat) {
              IntegerVector start = na_omit(Mat(_, 0)); // remove NAs from starts
              std::sort(start.begin(), start.end()); // sort starts
              IntegerVector end = na_omit(Mat(_, 1)); // remove NAs from ends
              std::sort(end.begin(), end.end()); // sort ends
              IntegerVector res = clone(start); // initialize vector for matching ends
              int j = 0;
              for (int i = 0; i < start.length(); i++) { // loop over starts
                while (end(j) < start(i) && j < (end.length() - 1)) { // find corresponding end
                  j++;
                }
                if (end(j) >= start(i)) res(i) = end(j); // assign end
                else res(i) = NA_INTEGER; // assign NA if no end >= start exists
              }
              return DataFrame::create(_["start"]= start, _["end"]= res); // return a data.frame
            }
            ')

Res <- fun(start_end)

library(data.table)
setDT(Res)
Res[, .(start = paste(start, collapse = ",")), by = end]
#   end    start
#1:   6    1,2,3
#2:   9      7,8
#3:  15 11,12,14
```

Answer (score 5):

Here's a solution built around [`findInterval()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/findInterval.html), [`split()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/split.html), and [`paste()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/paste.html):

```
m <- matrix(c(1,2,3,7,8,11,12,14,6,9,15,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA),ncol=2,dimnames=list(NULL,c('Start','End')));
data.frame(Start=sapply(split(m[,'Start'],findInterval(m[,'Start'],na.omit(m[,'End']))),paste,collapse=','),End=na.omit(m[,'End']));
##      Start End
## 0    1,2,3   6
## 1      7,8   9
## 2 11,12,14  15
```

---

**Edit:** The problem you encountered was due to the fact that in your real data some intervals between input `End` values do not contain any input `Start` values. My solution above is incorrectly omitting those intervals from the output `Start` vector, which causes a length mismatch against the output `End` vector.

Here is a fixed solution:

```
end <- na.omit(m[,'End']);
data.frame(Start=unname(sapply(split(m[,'Start'],findInterval(m[,'Start'],end))[as.character(0:c(length(end)-1))],paste,collapse=',')),End=end);
##      Start End
## 1    1,2,3   6
## 2      7,8   9
## 3 11,12,14  15
```

Here's a demonstration on a test matrix that has an empty interval:

```
m <- matrix(c(1,2,3,11,12,14,6,9,15,NA,NA,NA),ncol=2,dimnames=list(NULL,c('Start','End')));
m;
##      Start End
## [1,]     1   6
## [2,]     2   9
## [3,]     3  15
## [4,]    11  NA
## [5,]    12  NA
## [6,]    14  NA
end <- na.omit(m[,'End']);
data.frame(Start=unname(sapply(split(m[,'Start'],findInterval(m[,'Start'],end))[as.character(0:c(length(end)-1))],paste,collapse=',')),End=end);
##      Start End
## 1    1,2,3   6
## 2            9
## 3 11,12,14  15
```

As you can see, for an empty interval, the value that results in the output `Start` vector is the empty string, which I consider a sensible result. You can change the result afterward if desired.

Finally, here's a demo using the real data you posted to dropbox:

```
m <- read.table('start_end.txt',col.names=c('Start','End'));
head(m);
##   Start   End
## 1 11165 10548
## 2 12416 11799
## 3 12466 11900
## 4 12691 11976
## 5 12834 13336
## 6 13320 14028
end <- na.omit(m[,'End']);
system.time({ out <- data.frame(Start=unname(sapply(split(m[,'Start'],findInterval(m[,'Start'],end))[as.character(0:c(length(end)-1))],paste,collapse=',')),End=end); });
##    user  system elapsed
##  21.234   0.015  21.251
head(out);
##                           Start   End
## 1                               10548
## 2                         11165 11799
## 3                               11900
## 4                               11976
## 5 12416,12466,12691,12834,13320 13336
## 6       13425,13571,13703,13920 14028
nrow(out);
## [1] 131668
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I keep getting this error when I use a large matrix. Error in data.frame(Start = sapply(split(start_end[, "Start"], findInterval(start_end[,  : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 95954, 131668

Comment: Can you post your complete matrix somewhere, maybe pastebin or something? I'd have to see it to identify the issue.

Comment: There might be intervals that have no `Start` value.

Comment: In the output data.frame, what value do you want to use for `Start` for `End` values that have no input `Start` values in their interval? The empty string?

Comment: I tried using pastebin, but it exceeded the size limit. I hope dropbox does the job: https://www.dropbox.com/s/diy8io6b1t61oc8/start_end.txt?dl=0

Comment: There are no input Start values that are NA. There are always more start than end values.

Comment: The problem is not that input `Start` values are NA, it is that there are some intervals between input `End` values that do not contain any input `Start` values. My algorithm is incorrectly omitting those intervals from the output `Start` vector, which causes a length mismatch against the output `End` vector. I'm looking into how to solve this now.

Comment: Would there be a way to use a `with` instead of `sapply` in order to speed up this sorting process?

Comment: No, `with()` would not help here. The argument to `sapply()` is a list, which `sapply()` loops over, calling `paste()` once for each component, which is necessary to separately collapse each component vector to a single string. `with()` could theoretically allow you to access each component by name, but that wouldn't buy you anything, because you'd still have to call `paste()` once for each component, and there'd be no way to do so without knowing all the names in advance. Furthermore, even if you did know all the names, for many names, it would require a lot of hard-coded calls.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple base R version

```
with(as.data.frame(dat), {
  data.frame(
    Start=tapply(Start, cut(Start, c(0, End)), c),
    End=na.omit(End)
  )
})
#        Start End
# 1    1, 2, 3   6
# 2       7, 8   9
# 3 11, 12, 14  15
```

Another

```
with(as.data.frame(dat), {
  group <- as.integer(cut(Start, c(0, End)))                  # assign Start values to End groups
  data.frame(
    Start=unclass(by(dat, group, function(g) g[["Start"]])),  # combine Start groups
    End=unique(na.omit(End))                                  # Remove duplicate/NA End values
  )
})
```

Comment: Is the dat object a matrix?

Comment: @Chani The updated version works on your dropbox file, only takes about a second

Comment: @LegalizeIt I ran the updated version but Rstudio is still hung for a long time. I got the same exact error "arguments imply differing number of rows." Can you paste your complete source in pastebin? I'm curious to see if there are any differences between ours and what I'm doing wrong. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

An ugly `dplyr` solution:

```
library(dplyr)
df <- as.data.frame(df)

df %>% mutate(End = V2[findInterval(V1, na.omit(V2)) + 1]) %>%
       group_by(End) %>%
       summarise(Start = paste(V1, collapse=", "))
```

Edit - using findInterval thanks to @bgoldst